# How do I change the Duplicate Detection Window on an existing Windows Azure Service Bus topic?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Is it possible to change the Duplicate Detection Window on an existing Windows Azure Service Bus topic?

I am using C# to interact with Service Bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the core policy on an existing entity in the broker today.

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: There's no 'Update' for the policy, so there's lack of reference because that's not there. You'll just have to believe me - that might make sense because I work on Service Bus ;)

Comment: Ah, my apologies Clemens. I didn't realise it was you! By the way - your videos from the BUILD conference were great :)

Comment: By the way ... you can do updates now (introduced in 1.8 SDK)

Comment: You can update it now via the portal.  The range is 20 seconds to 7 days.  What I cannot figure out however is how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.duplicatedetectionhistorytimewindow.aspx

Alan Smith has a nice blog post (overview): http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2011/08/17/146556.aspx

Comment: If you enable Duplicate Detection using, for example the management console on windowsazure.com it defaults to 10 minutes. I am looking for a way to modify that property on an existing topic.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with Clemens on this one ;)